# How can I efficiently iterate through pairs within an array without duplicating?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, sorting

Assume I have 3 teams that each need to play each other once.  How can one efficiently iterate through them to schedule matches without duplicates?

```
    $teams = range('a', 'c');
    $games = array();
    foreach ($teams as $t1)
        foreach ($teams as $t2)
            if ($t1 != $t2)
                $games[] = $t1 . ' vs. ' . $t2;
    print_r($games);
```

Results in:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => a vs. b
        [1] => a vs. c
        [2] => b vs. a  <-- Duplicate of [0]
        [3] => b vs. c
        [4] => c vs. a  <-- Duplicate of [1]
        [5] => c vs. b  <-- Duplicate of [3]
    )
```

How can one efficiently avoid the duplicate matches?

The answer should yield:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => a vs. b
        [1] => a vs. c
        [2] => b vs. c
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generically:

```
Container C;
for (i = 0; i < C.size; ++i)
{
  for (j = i + 1; j < C.size; ++j)
  {
    /* have unique unordered set {i, j} */
  }
}
```

If you want the diagonal entries `(i, i)`, start at `j = i`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution isn't as elegant as @Kerrek's, but it does the same job:

```
$teams = range('a', 'c');
$games = Array();
$matched = Array();

foreach ( $teams as $t1 )
    foreach ( $teams as $t2 )
        if ( $t1 != $t2 )
            if ( !in_array( Array( $t1, $t2 ), $matched ) && !in_array( Array( $t2, $t1 ), $matched ) )
            {

                $games[] = $t1 . ' vs. ' . $t2;
                $matched[] = Array( $t1, $t2 );

            }

print_r( $games );
```

Comment: Thanks. Despite it not being as elegant, I actually used your version since it was more straight forward (for me) in php.